# how to make a css "if opera,not..."

Tags: css, opera

I want to make a css rule, which affects all but the opera browser, all the other browser add a css rule:

`#content{left:1px;}`, (opera without this rule). the below code not worked...

```
<!--[if !OPERA]> 
<style type="text/css">
#content{left:1px;} 
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4021618/946789

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the property you want for a selector like `#content{left:1px;}`  then add a css hack for opera providing the default value (or the value you want). The css hack has the following syntax: `@media all and (min-width:0px) {head~body .selector {property:value;}}` an example of the previous syntax and your example could be: `@media all and (min-width:0px) {head~body #content {left:0px;}}`

Answer (score 6):

Conditional comments are recognized by IE only. If you need Opera-specific CSS, you will need JavaScript:

```
if (window.opera) {
    document.getElementById('foo').style.height = '100px';
}
```