# If opera - something different in css?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there any way that I can override something in css and use different size if user/visitor uses opera?

Example, in chrome, ff and safari this works great:

```
.section#search h3 a {
    background: url("../img/search.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
    position: relative;
}
```

But in Opera padding is not really good... I need to add `top: 16px;` into it or to change padding to `padding: 0 0 36px 25px;`

Is there any "hack" like for IE or maybe javascript usage? No ideas...

All I need is to add that top or new padding just for opera. Thanks ;)

Comment: You might wanna detect the browser first.

Comment: Hmmm and how should I do that fella ?

Comment: Is it a php/asp page or is it an htm(l)?

Comment: Maybe this post would help you a bit.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120335/how-to-make-css-visible-only-for-opera

Comment: its html ... that thing looks good so far... I tested for one id only tho... But I hope it will work for others.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this behaviour in an online test case? I am really curious that you have this problem, I haven't come across such a problem for a very long time (and I use Opera daily, extensively).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the conditional-css tool, you can target opera, but engine is important. conditional-css.com explains:

> Conditional-CSS isn't really all that interested in which browser the
>   user is using, but rather what rendering engine the user's browser
>   utilises. This is why Conditional-CSS uses 'Gecko' rather than the
>   well known Firefox as one of it's browser conditions. Likewise for
>   Safari 'Webkit' is used. This allows other browsers using the same
>   rendering engines to receive the same targeted CSS. An exception to
>   this rule is made for IE (rather than using 'Trident') since this is
>   what the IE conditional comments use and Trident isn't particuarly
>   well known. Similarly for Opera, since only the Opera browser uses
>   it's Presto rendering engine, 'Opera' is used.

http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced

they write that a conditional tag is formed like:

```
[if {!} browser]
[if {!} browser version]
[if {!} condition browser version]
```

and that browser names are as follows:

```
IE - Internet Explorer
Gecko - Gecko based browsers (Firefox, Camino etc)
Webkit - Webkit based browsers (Safari, Shiira etc)
'SafMob' - Mobile Safari (iPhone / iPod Touch)
Opera - Opera's browser
IEMac - Internet Explorer for the Mac
Konq - Konqueror
IEmob - IE mobile
PSP - Playstation Portable
NetF - Net Front
```

So it should logically follow, according to them, that you can target via:
`[if Opera]`

like this in a CSS block:

```
[if Opera] .box {  
    width: 500px;  
    padding: 100px 0;  
}
```

or like this for a CSS include:

```
<!--[if Opera]>

<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a JavaScript library like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to test for browsers and use the css classes it adds to target Opera specifically.

Answer (score 1):

what versions and types of opera? you can use this media query

@media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  } 
to target opera 10, 10.5,11, and 11.6

check it out here: note, i only viewed in chrome19 and opera 11.6 http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/fw94a/

better

x:-o-prefocus, p{}

http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/6pRPC/

Answer (score 1):

Before you plan to use work-arounds and hacks, consider the following:

1. Is your page in strict mode? If not, add a doctype to the very first line of the page:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

   Otherwise, your page is in quirks mode, and it's the main cause of inconsistencies across browsers.
2. Try using a [CSS reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/). This should iron out little inconsistencies across browsers like paddings, margins, alignments and more. Load this style before any other styles.