# CSS works in Internet Explorer but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, css

Why does the code below work in IE, but not Firefox or Chrome? Is it the CSS or HTML?

CSS

```
body  {
background-image:url("\images\body_bg.png");
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color:#e0dfe4;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-size: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Program Letters</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../general.css"/>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for us? And what is the expected result?

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: I don't understand your claim that this doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox. You have repeat-x for background-repeat, but then you want background-attachment: scroll (default behavior), and you are setting background-size to auto. Nothing is wrong with your CSS. Are you claiming that your image isn't loading perhaps? If that is what you mean, then check for both path and file name with extension.

Comment: Could the backslash in `url("\images\body_bg.png")` be a culprit? Rough guess.

Comment: Try removing forward slash from the end of link tag.                              `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../general.css">` and also forward slash from meta tag since they are not allowed in HTML5

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093540/how-can-i-make-my-css-code-compatible-with-all-browsers

Comment: The background image isnt loading in Firefox or Chrome, but loads in IE. Here is the fidlle https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=m3yaxURRlB

Comment: I went to the fiddle, but nothing's there.

Answer (score 0):

It was a location issue in the CSS. The modified code below fixed it.

```
 body
{
    background-position: inherit;
    background-image: url("images/body_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: #e0dfe4;
}
```