# remove standard arrow from select dropdown in Opera (arrow in other browsers was fixed)

Tags: html, css, html-select, opera, css-shapes

I'm trying to hide the standard arrow from the select dropdown list.

I've resolved it for all browsers, thanks to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), but still can't remove or hide it for the Opera (my current version is Opera 12.16).

**Pure css solution is needed.**

```
select {
    background: url(/path/to/the/arrow.png) no-repeat center right;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
/*IE*/
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
/*FF*/
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    select {padding-right:5px;}
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: My customer wants that. I'm just trying to find a cross browser solution. Opera left.

Comment: Could you post what you've done so far? Ah, clients from hell... :)

Comment: have you used appearance for the rest browsers to get the effect???

Comment: The significant part of the code added. Thank you.

Comment: appearance is not accepted in opera..

Comment: "have you used appearance" - Yes.

Comment: Maybe you could wrap select element and one div which will hold image in one container, set position absolute to arrow image holder...http://jsfiddle.net/TXrKD/3/ something like this...

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm trying to find a pure css solution as I noted above. Thank you anyway for pointing that.

Comment: Hm... this is 'pure' css, no javascript or something... If you mean by 'pure css' -> to find solution just with existing elements... then, i have no clue. :D Hope someone will find a way... :)

Comment: appearance property is not supported in opera !! http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I didn't find the solution. However, what I did is I applied the style `background-image:none;` [for Opera only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120335/how-to-make-css-visible-only-for-opera) so only one standard arrow is displayed in Opera.