# How to detect the current browser

Tags: browser, browser-detection

Question: **Is there a easy way to detect the browser of the user ?**

Details: I would like to change *for example* the value of `background-color` of `body`. I've already see something like `<!--[if !IE]>`.

**Edit:**

Okay, I agree, [browser detect is bad](http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/) (Link taken from @TylerH), and should not be used. Thank I take note. And If someone really still want to use them, I've found a good website with a list of [browser detection hack](http://browserhacks.com/).

Comment: [Browser Detection Is Bad](http://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/)

Comment: Why ? Whit this, I can resolve compatibility problem for my website, no ?

Comment: Why are you wanting to detect a browser this way? A personal vendetta? It's best to just write standards-compliant code, and then where necessary, add browser-specific prefixes for your properties.

Comment: No, you wouldn't be resolving compatibility problems, you'd be masking compatibility problems. Fix the issue by addressing the problem, not the symptom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to do it with HTML or CSS (I don't like hacks).
But you could check the user agent string with JS.

See here: [How to make CSS visible only for Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120335/how-to-make-css-visible-only-for-opera)