# How to target Opera only with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, opera

I tried a few hacks but I wasn't able to effect Opera only. Is there a universal hack for all Opera versions?

The one below doesn't work.

```
@media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  
    p {  
        font-size:12px;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have to ask: ...why? Why do you want to only target Opera?

Comment: just -o like -o-min-device-pixel-ratio but you don't need it anymore because Opera uses webkit.

Comment: Unless you want to show some message like *You are using Opera*, there is no reason to just target Opera, there may be some difference between Opera and other webkit-based browsers (such as Chrome), but that difference is very little

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/lensco/EPN5M/

Comment: @KingKing even then you shouldn't be using CSS for this.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120335/how-to-make-css-visible-only-for-opera.

Comment: >> `universal hack for all Opera versions` ? why would you need it ? opera Presto and opera Blink are quite different, so to speak.