# How to make html Select box look same in all browsers on all Platforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, select

Hi i'm solving a problem to make select box look the same in all browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, IE) on all platforms. At present my Select box is working same in Firefox and Chrome But when i switch to Opera and IE. It behaves different from Firefox or Chrome. I haven't tried it on Safari yet. How i can do that ??

One more thing i would like to know is "Is it possible to make option tag look same in all browsers as they appear in Firefox in current fiddle ??" So far what i have studied is that it is not possible it is possible with UL LI only.

**HTML**

```
<label>
  <select>
    <option value="">Choose Category</option>
    <option value="">Category1</option>
    <option value="">Category2</option>
    <option value="">Category3</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
select{
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    color:#333;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
  width:40%;
  padding:0 5px;
  height:36px;
  -webkit-padding-before:8px;
  -webkit-padding-after:8px;
  font-size:14px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

select option{
    padding:8px 5px;
}


label {position:relative}
label:after {
    content:'<>';
    font:14px "Consolas", monospace;
    color:#333;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    right:8px; top:0px;
    padding:0 0 2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    right:6px; top:0px;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/6cf3Lfy6/

**Note:** I am testing it on Opera 12.12 and IE 11.0 and My Firefox and Chrome are up to date.

Comment: You can't unless you use a customised one like `select2` etc. It is because of different browsers have different default settings for rendering elements.

Comment: I think you are missing -o- support in your css for opera http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto27/css/o-vendor/

Comment: @codenut I tried but not working...

Answer (score 0):

All i reached is this far :

[see here](https://jsfiddle.net/6cf3Lfy6/10/)

```
padding:0px 5px 2px;
-o-transform:rotate(90deg);
```

[image]

still need to find way to increase padding in opera or top value

I have found a link i think i will be helpful if you once go through it

[How to make CSS visible only for Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120335/how-to-make-css-visible-only-for-opera)

and this too

[Select removing dropdown arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow)

Answer (score -1):

just try this, it should work
https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css

Comment: No this does not work, select elements width is different in firefox