# Future proof CSS selector for LTE Opera 10

Tags: css, opera, browser-detection

I am currently using `@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` to target Webkit browsers + Opera 9.2.

**Is there a safe* way to target Opera GTE 9.5 or LTE 10?**

<sub>* won't be picked up by another browser</sub>

Comment: Maybe you can explain what the real problem is (i.e. the issue you're trying to hack around)? Hacks are ugly and in my experience, rarely necessary.

Comment: just trying to get the same visual rendering for a form // 
it's quite challenging (the legend element for example) // 
misplaced labels and inputs // my target would be 9.5-10

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of the rendering difference ?

Comment: btw it's fixed in op 10.5 // negative margin-top on inputs and legend - but i can't feed it exclusively to op 9.5-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was hard but here it is. Works only in Opera gte 9.5 and lt 10.50:

```
@media all and (resolution = 0dpi) { // exclude Opera 10.50 and higher
  :root #box { // you need to append :root to all selectors to exclude Opera lt 9.5
    background: #f00;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is targeting only Opera. FF ignores it. Just try.

Comment: The key there is "0dpi" which seems to be "supported" but returned as true by all Opera versions < 10.50.

Comment: you didn't correctly pinpoint the culprit (it's related to http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#error-handling) // ill accept your solution if no one comes with something better and valid // you can use `(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
* targets Opera 9 & below (and perhaps future versions) - valid HTML & invalid XHTML */

#dis[disabled="true"]+p {}
```

Source: http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/08/27/css-hack-dumpster/

Comment: i tried it and it's not working (probably restricted to inputs)

Comment: v9.2 working
v10 not working (and that's what id like to target)