# How do I hide CSS from Opera 10.0 and earlier?

Tags: css, opera

Opera 10.0 has some bugs related to SVG background images. These are fixed in 10.5.

I’d like to use SVG background images for gradients in Opera, but hide the code from those poor souls still on Opera 10.0.

Does anyone know any CSS hacks or similar to hide CSS from Opera 10.0 and earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an answer here:

[Future proof CSS hack for LTE Opera 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243522/future-proof-css-hack-for-lte-opera-10)

this piece of code works only in Opera >= 9.5 and < 10.50:

```
@media all and (resolution = 0dpi) { // exclude Opera 10.50 and higher
  :root #box { // you need to append :root to all selectors to exclude Opera lt 9.5
    background: #f00;
  }
}
```

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it’ll do the job.