# Separate stylesheets

Tags: html, css, browser, opera

How could I use separate stylesheet for Opera?

Like:

```
<![if !IE 6]>
<link rel=»stylesheet» type=»text/css» href=»ctyle.css» />
<![endif]>
```

But for Opera? (For all versions of Opera)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a Chrome/Opera specific stylesheet ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945428/how-to-do-a-chrome-opera-specific-stylesheet)

Comment: What exactly do you need it for? There are some webkit specific tags that can be used to achieve very specific goals, for everything else, webkit should render similarly to gecko based browsers.

Comment: Wouldn't just about any method either rely on JavaScript or only work if the browser sent correct and uniquely identifiable user agent information?

Comment: @Razor Storm Doesn't Opera use a layout engine called *Presto*?

Comment: @Alex, oops, I was tired and read Opera as Chrome. (Yeah I know the words aren't even similar, no idea what I was thinking).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can without sniffing the user agent with server side code or JavaScript.

Besides the usual caveats of user agent sniffing, server side code would be more reliable as it wouldn't require JavaScript enabled.

There may also possibly be Opera specific hacks, but implementing these would be even worse than sniffing IMO.

If there are layout problems, I would [Google](http://google.com/search?q=opera+css+bugs) the bug and see what solutions exist to fix. You may not even need a separate stylesheet.