# Target two screen sizes on Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, css, media-queries

I'm using @media queries to make **only Chrome browsers** to position the ".l-triangle" in a specific position. So I'm using the following method

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
/* Fix for Chrome / Safari Users ONLY */

.l-triangle {
   background: transparent url('../images/menu_bg_left.gif') no-repeat;
   position: absolute;
   float: left;
   width: 55px;
   height:75px;
   display: block;
   left: 0px;
   top:0px;
   z-index: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

It works ok for Chrome browsers with screen size bigger than 968px but not on smaller than 968px.

My questions is how can I pass 2 different css values for **Chrome browsers only** with 2 different screen sizes?

Comment: Perhaps looking at the five `responsive-*.less` files for [Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) would give you some pointers. Although it's in LESS, the `@media` queries are still standard CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945428/how-to-do-a-chrome-opera-specific-stylesheet).

This code works only on Chrome:

```css
.chrome #thingie {
  do: this;
}
```

I hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use operators like "and" or "not" in your media queries.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-width: 968px) {
...code here...
}
```