# how to get a specific unicode character to display in Chrome/webkit browsers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, unicode

I have a page that needs to display the Unicode character &#9855 or &#x267f, the wheelchair symbol.

IE 11 and firefox display it correctly Chrome will not display it.

I am using the character as part of a CSS rule:

```
span.seat.Wheelchair:after{   
color:blue;   
content:"\267f";
}
```

Is there anyway to make this work in Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Chrome doesn't support Emoji at this time so there's really nothing you can do to make that character to show up. You can always try starring the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=151840&q=emoji&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) on the issue tracker but that probably won't bring about a fix any faster.

As a workaround, you can use an image of the wheelchair instead of the character itself or find a font that offers the character you are looking for. If you are adamant about using the specified character, you can try to modify the CSS only for your Chrome users (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945428/how-to-do-a-chrome-opera-specific-stylesheet) question).